# Derive weak formulation of a PDE from the integral form

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am taking a class about theory of elasticity. Therefore we cover some PDEs.

There is one exercise that puzzles my mind. We shall derive the weak/variational formulation from the following DE:

$\begin{align}-(a(x)u'(x)))' + b(x)u(x) &= f(x) \qquad x \in (0,l) \\ 
\alpha u'(0) - \beta u(0) &= 0 \\ 
\gamma u'(l) +\delta u(l) &= 0\end{align}$

but we shall do it from the **integral form:**

$a(x)u'(x) - a(0)u'(0) + \int_0^x (f(s) -b(s)u(s))ds = 0$

I really have no idea how to do that. Normally I would just multiply with some test function $v \in V$, integrate and then do partial integration.

But here ?! No idea.

I would be so thankful for any help.

EDIT: 
It seems that my question is misunderstood. 
I try it once again.

Given: 
$-\int_0^x(a(s)u'(s))'ds + \int_0^x  f(s)ds + \int_0^x b(s)u(s)ds = 0$ how can I derive the weak formulation?

Comment: you can start multiplying the equation by a test function $\phi$ and then integrate from $0$ to $\ell$.

Comment: which one to you mean? the original DE? because thats exactly what we are not supposed to do. We should start with the **integral form**

Comment: I assumed you are familiar with the Sobolev spaces

Comment: yes. I also did already FEM.

Comment: I get the point now but sorry this is interesting for me too

Answer (score 0):

we look for a weak solution $u\in H^1(0, \ell)$ satisfying the integral identity (weak formulation of the problem) $$\int_0^\ell u\bigg(-(a\phi')'+b\phi\bigg)dx=\int_0^\ell f\phi dx$$(obtained by twice integration by parts on the first term of the equation) for all $\phi\in C_0^\infty(0, \ell)$ and by density $$\int_0^\ell u\bigg(-(a\phi')'+b\phi\bigg)dx=\int_0^\ell f\phi dx$$ for all $\phi\in H_0^1(0, \ell)$.

Comment: I think you still did not get my quesiton. How can I derive this weak formulation if I start from the **integral form** and not with the **differential form**. What you explained above can be found in every FEM book.

Comment: since $\phi$ and its derivatives is zero at the endpoints $x=0$ and $x=\ell$ the boundary terms vanish during integration by parts

Comment: it seems that you do not even listen to what I am asking...

Comment: :) may be you are right I am doing this many times sorry for this

Comment: haha maybe i put the question so it is hard to understand. 
I reformed my quesition (see above), maybe you understand now what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write something obvious (too long for a comment), please do not misinterpret my aim.

Apart from elegance, what is fundamentally wrong with first going from the integral form to the differential form, and then to the weak formulation (via the usual proceudre you are familiar with)? It still fulfills the requirements of the exercise.

The integral to differential conversion is trivial, as $$a(x)u´(x) - a(0)u´(0) = \int_0^x (a(s) u´(s)) \mathrm{d}s$$ and  your differential expression is only a few passages away, waiting for the integration by parts machinery.

**ADDENDUM** Ok I just saw your edit in which you performed the integration on the first term. Well is that not all is there to do? If the integral expression is zero, will not the integrand be? And you have the DE.

Comment: Yeah I can see what you mean, and it was also my first intution to go back to the normal DE and then derive the weak formulation as usual. But I am not sure, if thats what they want. I am going to ask my professor tomorrow. But thanks for you help.

Comment: @Peter, let us know please, got me intrigued.

Comment: ah i forgot to ask :O 
i am waiting for an email from him anyways then i am going to ask. sorry

Comment: So he wrote me back (not very helpful): Multiply the integral formulation by v' and integrate. And play a little bit.